# Sub Domain redirection using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've been trying to get it to run properly for past few hours but no luck. I've tried all kind of codes I found online.

So I have images.website.com and I want to redirect all content of it to images.website.org (tld change).

I manged to do the homepage redirect but my original images don't redirect to .org.

Image URL: http://images.website.com/images/123.png

Once users load that image directly in their browser I'd like it to point to http://images.website.org/images/123.png

I'm using Apache and htaccess.

Thanks guys!

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the document root of **images.website.com**

```
Redirect 301 / http://images.website.org/
```

If both **images.website.com** and **images.website.org** have the same document root, you can try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^images.website.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://images.website.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```